# A Fourier series failing to converge on the Cantor Set

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

This is a strengthening of Chandru's question:

[Example of a function whose Fourier Series fails to converge at One point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2227/)

Is there a nice and concrete example of a Fourier series that fails to converge on some "big" set of measure zero, for instance on the Cantor ternary set?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an exact answer for this but I think this paper might help:

[*Pointwise convergence of multiple Fourier series using different convergence notions*](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01908456)

---

One more link:

In this paper the authors show that for any set of zero measure there exists a continuous function on the circle whose Fourier series diverges on that set. In French.

*Sergei Vladimirovich Konyagin, On divergence of trigonometrique Fourier series everywhere, C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris 329 (1999), 693-697*.

Comment: @George S: Why no comments to the answer. Havent you seen the article.

Comment: @Chandru: Thanks for the article. Why I was not commenting was simply because this paper is apparently proving a general fact(which you had indicated in your question) and I was looking for some nice concrete example instead.