# Convergent Fourier series of continuous function

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f$ be a continuous function. It is known that its Fourier series is convergent almost everywhere to $f$ and it may fail to converge on some measure zero set. However I would like to know whether one can find a continuous function $f$ with the property that its Fourier series is convergent everywhere but not to $f$ (in other words for each $x$ the partial sums $S_N(x)$ converge to $S(x)$ and there are some points $x$ such that $S_N(x)$ converges to $S(x)\neq f(x)$).

Comment: When you talk about the convergence of the Fourier series of $f$, is it pointwise convergence, or $L^2$ convergence?

Comment: Convergent everywhere=pointwise for each point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the partial sums $S_N(x)$ converge to $S(x)$, then the Cesaro sums
$$
\sigma_N(x)=\frac1N\sum_{k=1}^NS_N(x)
$$
also converge to $S(x)$. But the Cesaro sums of a continuous function $f$ converge uniformly to $f$, so that $S(x)=f(x)$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem whether the Fourier series of any continuous function converges almost everywhere was posed by Nikolai Lusin in the 1920s, resolved positively in 1966 by Lennart Carleson in $L^2$ and generalized by Richard Hunt to $L^p$ for any $p > 1$. This result is known as the Carleson–Hunt theorem.

This [article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0307008v4.pdf) may help.

Andrey Kolmogorov, as a student at the age of 19, constructed an example of a function in $L^1$ whose Fourier series diverges almost everywhere [(Original Article)](https://books.google.fr/books?hl=fr&lr=&id=ikN59GkYJKIC&oi=fnd&pg=PR13&dq=diverge+partout+authornbsp:kolmogorov&ots=2OvYAnZNwa&sig=BXuHcDly4I-RQM1rRSuUCmWSZKY#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: You answered another question, not the one which I asked

Comment: The Carleson–Hunt theorem states that if $f\in L^p$, for $p>1$, the Fourier series exists and converges to $f$ almost everywhere. Kolmogorov constructed a funcion $f\in L^1$ for which the Fourier series exists (it satisfies the weak Dirichlet's condition) but diverges almost everywhere. So this may be the example you are looking for.

Comment: I know those results: what I'm looking for is a continuous function $f$ with the property that its Fourier series converges everywhere to _something_ (let us call this sum $S(x)$) but this _something_ is different from $f$. Taking into account Carleson theorem obviously the set of points $x$ for which $S(x) \neq f(x)$ is of measure zero. I'm not interested in divergent series, I'm intersted in comparing the value of this sum with initial function $f$. Is it now clear?

Answer (score 0):

@JuliánAguirre 's answer is correct.

But that's true only if the partial sum $S_N(x)$ converges at every $x$.

I guess what OP wanted to ask was if one could find a function $f$ whose Fourier series $S(x)$ doesn't converge to $f$ at some point. Note that this needs not to mean that $S(x)$ converges at every point. If $S(x)$ diverges at some point, then it clearly doesn't converge to $f$.

So I want to post a useful and relevant fact here.

**Fact:** There exist a continuous function $f$ whose Fourier series doesn't converge to $f$ on a null set (i.e. set of zero measure).

Here is a constructive proof from an anonym, c.f. [Example of a function whose Fourier Series fails to converge at One point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2227/example-of-a-function-whose-fourier-series-fails-to-converge-at-one-point).

And here is an abstract proof from Wikipedia, c.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Pointwise_convergence.